# Библиотека beautifulsoup4 сразу не подключается в проекте в PyCharm

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, pycharm, проект, библиотека

Я скачал библиотеку beautifulsoup4 и после скачивания чтобы подключить мне приходится находить её в файлах и добавлять в проект. Так должно быть? Или я что-то криво сделал. Всё что я сделал это в терминале PyCharm прописал pip install beautifulsoup4 и попробовал сразу применить её (from bs4 import BeautifulSoup)

Comment: Скачали или установили? Невозможно точно ответить без понимания того что именно вы делали.

Comment: Я исправил @МихаилРебров